# PYGame - How to stop and close window by pressing a Key?

Tags: python, pygame

I have created a script using PYGAME to animate a pendulum motion simulation. I want to press a "q" key to stop the simulation and close the window. I tryed many different codes but all return some error. The lest version of the event part of the code was:

```
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
            
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_t:
                is_tracing = not(is_tracing)
            if event.key == K_c:
                trace.fill(WHITE)
            if event.key == K_q:
                done = True
        break
```

The "c" and "t" events are running fina and the "q" idead stops the simulation, but the simulation window frezes and I need to reestart the kernel do make it run again. Any idea of how to make it close the window without Killing the kernel?

I am runing the code at Jupter Notebook 6.1.4 from Anaconda Navigator 1.10 and Python 3.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Any idea of how to make it close the window without Killing the kernel?*

Try using `pygame.quit()`. From [pygame FAQ](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)

> Make sure, you invoke pygame.quit() on exiting your application or game.

```
# ... running = True
while running:
    event = pygame.event.wait ()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False  # Be IDLE friendly
pygame.quit ()
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. I just need to remember to put the rest of the code after the events definition and before the pygame.quit ()